# Running a npm: "Symbol is not defined"

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I'm trying to use: https://github.com/siddharthkp/cost-of-modules
I have npm3 installed on Centos 6.4. When I try to run it I got this error:

```
[root@XXX public]# cost-of-modules

Making sure dependendies are installed
npm install --production


Calculating...


/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cost-of-modules/lib/helpers.js:167
                throw _iteratorError2;
                      ^
ReferenceError: Symbol is not defined
    at Object.getSizeForNodeModules (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cost-of-modules/lib/helpers.js:145:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cost-of-modules/lib/index.js:19:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

Don't know why it calls to "npm install" I already have npm3 installed. I already asked in the Github's module but I thinks it's not related to that specific module. Please, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Having a similar issue, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: See this https://github.com/siddharthkp/cost-of-modules/issues/24

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug on cost-of-modules. It's solved now here:

https://github.com/siddharthkp/cost-of-modules/issues/24